# Stationary distribution of a Markov chain with a random transition matrix

Tags: markov-process, dirichlet-distribution

Consider a Markov chain $\{X_t\}$ on a finite state $\mathcal{S} = \{1,\dots, S\}$ space whose transition matrix $P$ is populated by elements of the form
$$ p_{ij} = P(X_{t+1} = j | X_t = i)$$
and we know that the $S$ vector $p_i = (p_{i,1},\dots, p_{i,S})$ follows a Dirichlet distribution with concentration parameter $(\alpha_{i1},\dots,\alpha_{iS})$, and this is true for $i \in \mathcal{S}$. Does the notion of an associated stationary distribution make sense in this context? And if so, can it be described in terms of a Dirichlet distribution?

Comment: @Xi'an No, but you only know the distribution of the elements, not the realizations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition matrix $P$ is almost surely strongly irreducible, hence produces a Markov chain with a stationary distribution $\pi$ associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda_1=1$ of $P$, i.e., $\pi P=\pi$. According to [this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00310528/document), when $S$ grows to infinity, $\pi$ converges to the uniform distribution in total variation.

When considering the case $S=2$, the stationary distribution associated with$$P=\left(\begin{matrix} 1-a &a\\ b &1-b\end{matrix} \right)$$
is$$\pi=(b\ \ a)\big/(a+b)$$where $a\sim\mathcal B(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ and $b\sim\mathcal B(\alpha_2,\alpha_1)$, which shows $\pi$ is not a Dirichlet variate.

Comment: What about with fixed $S$?

Comment: Right, thanks, I accepted the answer. May I ask about the case before where a new realization was drawn at each $t$?

Comment: This is a very interesting case, but while there is a stabilisation due to the finite state space, I thought the chain cannot be stationary in the Markov sense, since the transition varies at each time.  See however this answer on [math overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/211322/64496) that shows the opposite, by integrating out the Markov matrix.